# Can I use proguard to strip off methods or classes?

Tags: android, android-build

I am modifying a library in which i am calling methods of a class using reflections.

I need this class to be stripped off after using proguard.

Are classes instantiated by reflections removed by default? Or do I need to make changes to proguard-properties.txt to remove them explicitly?

Are they removed at all or just obfuscated?

Answer (score 0):

If you use *Android.mk* to compile the module, you can add this line to the makefile:

```
DISABLE_PROGUARD := true
```

If you compile an app using eclipse, you can comment the *project.properties*:

```
#proguard.config=
```